# Method for finding implicit equations $Ax=0$ that describe a subspace with known base.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, numerical-linear-algebra

Let $V$ a vector space and $U$ a subspace of $V$. Let $B_U$ a basis of $U$. How can you find a matrix $A$ such that $x\in V \iff Ax=0$? That is, I want to find the implicit description of a subspace with a given basis. I know how to do for concrete exercises, but I'd like to know a simple algorithm that I can use on the PC. I've been searching and I read the following.

Suppose the basis of the subspace is given in the rows of a matrix $B$. If $M=null(B)$ gives a matrix whose columns are the basis of the subspace given by the implicit equations $Bx=0$, then $M'$ gives the coefficients of the implicit equations of the subspace.

Why is that? I've read that it might have to do with orthogonal complement, but I think it must be simpler... just using the definition.

An example:
Let $U$ the subspace $\mathbb{R}^3$ with basis $\{(1,0,0), (0,1,0)\}$. To find the implicit equations, one would do write a generic element of $U$ as a linear combination of the vectors of the basis, so

\begin{equation}\left(
\begin{matrix}
x\\
y\\
z
\end{matrix} \right)
= \lambda \left(\begin{matrix}
1\\
0\\
0
\end{matrix} \right) + \mu \left(\begin{matrix}
0\\
1\\
0
\end{matrix} \right) = \left(\begin{matrix}
\lambda\\
\mu\\
0
\end{matrix} \right)
\end{equation}

So the conclusion is that $z=0$, and this is the implicit equation describing the subspace.

With the other method, one would write

B =\begin{equation}\left(
\begin{matrix}
1&0&0\\
0&1&0
\end{matrix} \right)\end{equation}

and find $null(B)$, which is the column vector $(0,0,1)'$. In $null(B)$ there are the coefficients of the implicit equation, $(0x+0y+) 1z=0$.

Why does this works?
Thanks in advance

Comment: (I suppose $M'$ denotes the transpose matrix $M^T$.) Where have you been reading that? It is wrong, and not even coherent as for the (co-)dimensions. E.g. the plane $U$ in $V=\mathbb R^3$ generated by the *two* vectors  $(1,2,3)^T$ and $(4,5,6)^T$ has *one* equation: $x-2y+z=0.$

Comment: @AnneBauval I this case $B$ is a matriz whose first row is $(1,2,3)$ and whose second row is $(4,5,6)$. Then null(B) is a column vector, $(1,-2,1)'$. The elements of this vector are the coefficients of the implicit equation: $(1,-2,1)(x,y,z)'=0$ is precisely $x-2y+z=0$.

Comment: @AnneBauval If I made a typo that makes difficult to read the question, please warn me so I can correct it.

Comment: It is more a generalized misunderstanding than a typo. If the implicit equations of $U$ are $Bx=0$, then "$null(B)$" denotes the kernel of the linear map with matrix $B$ (which you want to deduce from your matrix $M$ whose columns form a basis of $U$). In your example, $M=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&1\end{pmatrix}$. In mine, $M=\begin{pmatrix}1&4\\2&5\\3&6\end{pmatrix}$ and $B=\begin{pmatrix}1&-2&1\end{pmatrix},$ and $null(M^T)$ is a line, which has nothing to do with $null(B).$

Comment: @AnneBauval Hm, ok. I have a  matrix B whose rows are the vectors of the basis of the subspace $U$. I want to find the implicit expresion of my subspace, that is, find $A$ such that $Ax =0 \iff x \in U$.  Tool: in different softwares, we have the comand null(B). It returns a matrix whose columns are the element of the basis of the subspace given by $Bx=0$. Claim: if $B$ is a matriz whose rows contains the element of a basis of $U$, then null(B) return a matrix whose traspose contains the coefficient of the implicit equations:   Coef = null(B), Coef.' * [x,y,z]' gives the implicit equations.

Comment: @AnneBauval I tried to clarify a little, not sure if I succeed..

Comment: If you find the reason why is correct, please tell me, it is driving me crazy. Thanks for taking the time in reading me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "reason why" can be explained without the notion of orthogonal complement.

Let $B$ be your matrix such that the columns of its transpose $B'$ form your basis $B_U=(B_1,\dots,B_r)$ of $U,$ and let "$null(B)=C$" be a matrix whose columns $C_1,\dots,C_s$ form a basis of $\ker B.$ Then these columns belong to $\ker B$, so that

$$BC_j=0\quad\forall j=1,\dots,s.$$

More compactly: $BC=0,$ or $C'B'=0'=0,$ i.e. $C'B_i=0$ for all $i=1,\dots,r,$ i.e. $C'U=0,$ so the lines of $C'$ (or the columns of $C$) are coefficients of implicit equations for $U.$

But I should improve that answer by being more careful about the ranks of these matrices, to establish that $U$ is *exactly* the kernel of $C'$ (and not a proper subsspace of it).

Or more directly, using orthogonal complements:
$$\ker(C')={\rm im}(C)^\bot=\ker(B)^\bot={\rm im}(B')=U.$$

Comment: Let me make sure that I understood everything. When you are in the step $C'B'=0$, then you deduce that $C'B_i'=0$ being $B_i'$ the columns of the traspose of $B$, right? Since $B_i'$ are the vectors of the basis of $U$, then you have that $C'x=0$, being $x$ any vector in $U$. In other words, we have found the matrix of coefficients of the implicit equations of $U$.

Comment: Yes. Your $B'_i$'s are what I called $B_i$. Your "$C'x=0$ for any$x\in U$" is what I wrote $C'U=0.$

Comment: Thanks a lot for putting the effort in writing the explanation and answering my questions!